# Drop-down menu appears when hovering over content area

Tags: css, menu

For some reason, I hover over the area below the main navigation tabs and it brings up the drop down menu.  I've been trying to figure this out and I'm trying to avoid writing it from the beginning.

Any help?

Here's the CSS code I have:

```
#primary_nav_wrapper {     
    position: relative; 
    top: 85px;      
    width: 100%;        
    height: 39px; 
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(90,90,90);
}

#primary_nav {

    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 2.5%;
    width: 95%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* Affects parent tabs only ============================================================================*/

#primary_nav > ul#all_parent_tabs {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0; 
    /* ^ Resets margin for the parent tabs in th primary nav. Removing affects position*/
    padding: 0; 
    /* ^ Resets padding for the parent tabs in th primary nav. Removing affects position*/
    height: 100%; 
    /*Sets ul*/
    list-style-type: none; 
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
}


#primary_nav > ul#all_parent_tabs > li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}

#primary_nav > ul#all_parent_tabs > li > a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(133,133,133);
}

#primary_nav > ul#all_parent_tabs > li.parent_tabs_one_line > a{
    line-height: 39px;
}

#primary_nav > ul#all_parent_tabs > li.parent_tabs_two_line > a{
    padding: 4px 0 0 0;
}

#primary_nav > ul#all_parent_tabs > li:hover {
    background-color: rgb(248,248,248);
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}


#primary_nav > ul#all_parent_tabs > li:hover > ul.drop_down_menu li a{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: .4s all .4s;
    -moz-transition: .4s all .4s;
    -ms-transition: .4s all .4s;
    -o-transition: .4s all .4s;
    transition: .4s all .4s;
}

#primary_nav > ul#all_parent_tabs > li#active_tab {
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(65,217,28);
    background-color: rgb(248,248,248);
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
}

/* For drop-down menu ==================================================================================*/


#primary_nav > ul#all_parent_tabs > li > ul.drop_down_menu {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 262px;
    width: 140%;
    top: 39px;
    text-align: left;
}

#primary_nav > ul#all_parent_tabs > li > ul.drop_down_menu > li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 140%;
    height: 26px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: block;
}

#primary_nav ul#all_parent_tabs > li > ul.drop_down_menu > li > a{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 5px; 
    display: block;
    width: 140%; 
    background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
    border: 1px solid rgb(205,205,205);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(150,150,150);
    z-index: 1;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

#primary_nav ul#all_parent_tabs > li:hover > ul.drop_down_menu > li > a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(233,254,237);
    -webkit-transition: all .2s;
    -moz-transition: all .2s;
    -ms-transition: all .2s;
    -o-transition: all .2s;
    transition: all .2s;
```

Comment: Where is your HTML? Can you make a JSFiddle so we can see it in action?

Comment: here's a link to the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v9v5j/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is to do with the fact that `ul.drop_down_menu` is not set to hidden, but rather its child elements (a tags). For this reason, hovering over `ul.drop_down_menu` still triggers the hover state of its parent li tag (which is what triggers your transitions).

Adding this solves the problem:

```
ul.drop_down_menu {
    visibility:hidden;
}
li:hover ul.drop_down_menu {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/v9v5j/2/)

Comment: You're a genius. Thanks so much!!! You have no idea how much I appreciate the help.

Comment: @user3643141 Welcome to StackOverflow, and I'm glad I could help. You can express you appreciation upvoting good answers, and using the green tick to accept answers that are helpful.

Comment: There was just one issue with the snippet you wanted to add. It takes away the fade in effect from the dropdown menu.  I was looking to keep that in.  Is there a way to fade in the drop down menu?

Comment: try using `visibility: hidden` and `visibility:visible` instead of display

Comment: @Chris M ...That's what I had at first but doing so makes the drop down menu appear even when not hovering on the main tabs.

Comment: i just added Lego's code to [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/v9v5j/2/) and changed it to visibility and it worked great for me.  I truthfully haven't looked at your code at all, but it sounds like a css cascading issue like Lego said

Comment: I'm scratching my head as to why that works. I thought the whole issue in the first place revolved around the fact that an element with visibility:hidden can still be hovered over. Edit: Ah, seems ul.drop_down_menu was never set to hidden to begin with, only its child elements. visibility vs. display had nothing to do with this.

Comment: I think, had too many vodkas, but transitions don't work with `display:none` the way they do with `visibility:hidden`.  wish I could get the 15 rep for the updated answer.